# Send Custom notifications using firebase android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

How can we send custom notifications using firebase. I want the notifications to open up the specific page in the android application on notifications click action.

Comment: I have around 6 -7 pages in my android app, When i send firebase notifications and when user clicks it, always the home page of the app is opened. I want to open specific page/content on notofication click, can we control that through the click_action in CUSTOM KEY VALUE pair in firebase, if so how?

Comment: you can use pending intent to open specific activity and send extras in pending intent to point to specific intents